# Read two lines of CSV at a time (Java)

Tags: java, csv

Is there a way to read two lines of a csv file at a time in Java?

I can read one at a time using Scanner (it has to be done like this):

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] nline = line.split ("[,]");
......
```

Here is some sample data and a short explanation. I need these read two at a time so I can can go about my other processing.

the first line that starts with "Create" creates a person
the second line "action" is the action of the created person

```
create,Mr. Jones,blah,blah 
action,1,3
create,Mrs.Smith,blah,blah
action,4,10
....
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cory's answer is good but for your next part to work

```
String[] nline = line.split ("[,]");
......
```

You need to add the comma in there

```
String line = input.nextLine() + "," + input.nextLine();
```

Comment: This won't work if you have data like: create,"Smith, John",blah - the split would also catch the , after Smith which is really field data.

Comment: @Jeremy You are right but that is a problem with the delimiter and not the solution. If his data does contain those characters even without this he would have a problem. A better delimiter would be a tab '\t'

Comment: Aye - but he may not have control of the source of data, really pure speculation at this point.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to parse CSV files in Java I'd avoid line split via the string.split() method. You can run into issues if your field contains commas. For Java I'd recommend [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse the data. Similar to using the scanner you can read it in line by line, or slurp the entire file if it's not too large, and just iterate over the list to items at a time.

```
CSVReader reader = ...
String[] firstLine; // fields from first line
String[] secondLine; // fields from second line

while ((firstLine = reader.next()) != null && (secondLine = reader.next()) != null) {
   // do something with two lines        
}
```

Or

```
CSVReader reader = ...
List<String[]> allLines = reader.readAll();
// TODO: validate we have an even number of lines

for (int i = 0; i < allLines.size(); i += 2) {
   String[] firstLine = allLines.get(i);
   String[] secondLine = allLines.get(i+1);

   // do something with two lines
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String line = input.nextLine() + input.nextLine();
```